# C# How to return Button array from a function

Tags: c#, arrays, button, return, controls

Hello i have this method which creates an array of buttons and i want to have it wrap in method because i will use it couple times :

```
        void CreatingButtons(int n, List<string> names)
    {
        Button[] Buttons = new Button[n];
        int horizontal = 180; int vertical = 5;
        int Height = 33; int Width = 350 / Buttons.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < Buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            Buttons[i] = new Button();
            Buttons[i].Height = Height;
            Buttons[i].Width = Width;
            this.Controls.Add(Buttons[i]);
            Buttons[i].Text = names[i];
            Buttons[i].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            Buttons[i].Location = new Point(horizontal, vertical);
            horizontal += Buttons[i].Width;
            Buttons[i].Click += (o, k) => { };
        }
    }
```

and i want to return the newly created array of buttons in here

```
        private void bHow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> buttonNames = new List<string> { "Dealing the Cards", "Betting Blind", "How to Properly Bet" };
        CreatingButtons(3, buttonNames);
        //Button [] getTheButtonArrayHere = CreatingButtons() or something like this
    }
```

Comment: How are you going to return anything here `private void bHow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` when `void` means it does not return anything ... change the method signature to return Buttons[]

Comment: @MethodMan I'm pretty sure he meant "get the button array here" and not "return"

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I'm quite sure he didn't \

Comment: @MethodMan Then that would probably be a problem. If the naming hasn't been changed by hand, you cannot make a Button's Click Event return type to be anything other than void. If the naming was changed or if this is not attached to a button's click event, I'll stand corrected.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath not to worry .. just making a quick observation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you at least tried this?

```
Button[] CreatingButtons(int n, List<string> names)
{
    //your code...
    return Buttons; // return the Button array
}

// blablabla
Button[] getTheButtonArrayHere = CreatingButtons(someIntVariable, someListOfStringVariable);
```